# Matlab matrix command issue

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can this MATLAB command work assuming that I is an image and Y a 1*256 vector?

```
img=round(y(I));
```

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the matrix of the image (created from using I=imread('./imagefile.png') or whatever) are apparently within the range 0 to 255 (or maybe you shifted them from 1 to 256?) and they are being used as the value for the index into y. E.g., you get a matrix returned that looks like

```
round(y(I(1,1))) round(y(I(1,2)) round(y(I(1,3)) ...;
round(y(I(2,1))) round(y(I(2,2)) ...
...
```